# Modelling a balancing act on a rope with concentration/madness.

Tags: functions

Nonmathematician here so please be kind. I looking for a function where y either approaches 1 from 0 or 1 from 2 with increasing values of x.

To elaborate with a real-life phenomenon. Assume a person standing on a rope. He falls when he leans to the right (y=0 approx). He falls when he leans to the left(y=2 approx). But when his concentration increases (x) he balances really well (y=1 approx). Further assuming that he can go mad (x can be negative) and as the madness increases he falls to the right (y=0 approx) or to the left (y=2 approx).
please help

Comment: Not sure I understand.  Take the function $y=x+1$ that is increasing and as $x$ tends to $0$ $y$ tends to $1$.  Is that good enough?

Comment: @lulu as x tends to infinity y tends to 1 either from upper bound 2 or lower bound 0. Thanks for the response :).

Comment: Is $x$ positive only, or can it be negative too?

Comment: @T.Linnell x can take negative values but the effect will reverse. That is, as x tends to - infinity y tends to either 0 or 2.

Comment: By "the effect will reverse", do you mean that as $x$ goes towards negative infinity, then $y$ will go to $1$? Or does it do something different?

Comment: So you want $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=1$ and you want $f(x)$ to be increasing form some starting point ($0$ or $1$), yes?

Comment: What does it mean for a function to approach $1$ (or tend to $1$) *from $2$* (or *from an upper bound*)?

Comment: If my interpretation is correct (highly doubtful) then the [Logistic Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function) might be what you are looking for.

Comment: Does $f(x) = 1 - \frac 1 x$ for positive real values $x$ do it?

Comment: Actually, I have a y variable that could take values (0,2) but will approach 1 when x tends to + infinity. OR y will approach either 0 or 2 when x tends to - infinity.

Comment: @lulu yes. starting point either 0 or 2. excluding 0 or 2

Comment: So, just restrict my function to whatever domain you like.  Mine is smooth and increasing for all real $x$.

Comment: In that case $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}$ (the logistic function) should satisfy the requirements. As $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=1$ and $\lim_{x\to -\infty}f(x)=0$ and for no $x\in \mathbb{R}$ $f(x)=0$ or $f(x)=0$ holds.

Comment: I get the impression that you have a lot more restrictions on the function than you are sharing.  Your last comment doesn't even require that the function be increasing...did you drop that or did you forget to add it?  I think it would help a lot if you asked one clear question.  State exactly what properties you require, no options.

Comment: In that case, just as @lulu suggested, the logistic function is probably what you want. You can play about with the parameters to get the exact behaviour you want (like if you want $y$ to have a certain value when $x=0$). As it is, your conditions are actually rather vague, and there are a lot of functions that satisfy them - $\frac{1}{\pi}\arctan{x}+\frac{1}{2}$ works for example.

Comment: Apologies if I am still not clear. I think @BoazMoerman has got the half solution. What I need more is direction of approach of y.

Comment: What do you mean precisely with "direction of approach of y"?

Comment: @BoazMoerman Lets tackle the problem part by part. first, possible values of y (0,1) , y increases (decreases) with increase (decrease) in x. Second, possible values of y (1,2), y decreases (increases) with an increase (decrease) in x.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want the function f to be a function of two variables $f(x,y)$ with the value of $f(x,y)$ representing the height of the person. Is that what you meant?

Comment: @lulu, Kindly review my question I have added an example as I am not able to elaborate mathematically.

Comment: @BoazMoerman Please reread the question. The gist is y closer to 1 (being balanced) is "good thing" and increasing values of x  is "good thing" ( as high concentration is good thing for balancing act).

Comment: @T.Linnell please read this question for more clarity https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/296802/bounded-variable-with-bad-extreme-values

Comment: @k.stm Is the question clear now?

Comment: But if someone is unbalanced, the person could be leaning right or left. So the value of $x$ does not uniquely define the value of $y$, if I understand you correctly. If you indeed mean that, the multivalued function $y(x)=1\pm\frac{1}{1+e^x}$ should suffice.

Comment: Well, I don't understand.  it now looks like you want some probabilistic thing....so a random variable.

Comment: @lulu First I want to model it deterministically.

Comment: @BoazMoerman :) I have verified manually. It is what I need. Kindly consider writing an answer.

Comment: Thank you all for the time and patience. You people are really cordial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The multivalued function $y(x)=1\pm\frac{1}{1+e^x}$ suffices the requirements, as $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=1$, $\lim_{x\to -\infty}f(x)=1\pm1=\{0,2\}$. Additionally, the multivalued function is monotone and differentiable.

Comment: Please also try to solve this regression problem based on this answer if possible. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/296802/bounded-variable-with-bad-extreme-values  Thank you very much

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't taken a statistics course yet (except a really limited form of testing hypotheses I learned in high school). I will take one in the upcoming year, but as of now, I cannot solve that regression problem.